# Polygon count budget

Tags: unity, 3d

Is there any smart way to think about polygon budget relating to PC gaming today? 
My game will have one static 3d background scene and two fighters. No more enemies. I am thinking about having animated 3d models in the background for atmosphere, like spectators.

So how could i find out what the polygon count for the player models and background scenarios could be. I guess the question is, what is a for today typical polygon count that most PCs can handle?

Comment: There's no typical poly count, as there is no typical PC. It really depends. What is a fairly common low-end machine of your game's targeted players? You can then estimate based on the theoretical polygon count the GPU can crunch by dividing that with the most number of models on the screen. You're probably looking at a relatively large number. Fillrate and shader pipelines are much more crucial to rendering performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a for today typical polygon count that most PCs can handle

I would say according to current generation consoles -ps3/xbox360- and not counting next-gen it's usually around 10k for the main characters which is reasonable taking into account quality/performance in the current gen. For enemies it's around 2k-5k, depending on how important they are. Given that PS3/XBOX 360 are 7 years old** I can safely say *most* today's PCs can handle that.

#### The problem though

Polygon count is a tangible number (and FPS per se) yet alone is not really an accurate or even good indication of the overall game performance. There is much more in your game than poly count; fillrate, draw batches, fragment shaders, rendering passes, culling..etc the best way is to profile your application and find your bottleneck. Real time rendering is a great book for different visual appearance and optimization techniques it even has a full chapter dedicated for [pipeline optimization](http://www.realtimerendering.com/#pipeopt)

**I didn't take into account that PS3/XBOX 360 are optimized for rendering/games.

> I am thinking about having animated 3d models in the background for
>   atmosphere, like spectators.

Well, depending on your game; but the question is, why use fully detailed 3D models while they may not really add much to the game because they are not actually at the very center?
Most games don't use real 3D models for spectator look at Fifa for example, they use 2d images without losing much of the atmosphere.